# Delete table column content

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

| car | score | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Opel | 30 | 43 |
| Volvo | 500 | 434 |
| Kia | 50 | 3 |
| Toyota | 4 | 4 |
| Mazda | 5000 | 4 |

How I can delete all the content of table column `score` without changing the table structure?

Expected result:

| car | score | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Opel |  | 43 |
| Volvo |  | 434 |
| Kia |  | 3 |
| Toyota |  | 4 |
| Mazda |  | 4 |

Comment: You mean `UPDATE cars SET score = NULL;`?

Comment: I want with one SQL query to delete all values: 30, 500, 50, 4, 5000

Comment: This might be a problem with terminology, but in SQL you can *delete* only full rows. If you want to keep the rows but get rid of the values in one column, that means you must overwrite them with a different value - that might be `0`, `-1`, `NULL` or really anything.

Comment: ok, updating them to `0` is also an option for me. Can you post an example query?

Comment: I already did post one that updates `score` in all rows to `NULL`.

Comment: Please include the expected result in the question.

Comment: Done. Post is updated.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by Bergi, you have the option of setting all values in the column to NULL or 0, depending on what you need, or you can delete the entire column.

Solution 1:

```
UPDATE cars SET score = NULL;
```

or

```
UPDATE cars SET score = 0;
```

This will preserve the `score` column but set all the values to NULL or 0 respectively. Note that NULL and 0 are different things. NULL means the field is empty but 0 means the field has the numerical value 0.

If you don't need the `score` column anymore, you can delete it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE cars
DROP COLUMN score;
```

This will delete the column `score` and you will not be able to use it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer by gowner is ok.

However in case you have no permission to alter table structure, you cannot delete column.

And given the `score` field is not nullable,
you cannot update the field to null.

You must be careful that updating the score to 0 may not be ideal.
0 may have different meaning in your table. Maybe minimum score is 1 and 0 is not a possible value in the field. Or a consensus in your organization that -1 means "no value". They should be relfected in the default constraint or guidelines of your organization.

I would prefer to be safe

```
UPDATE cars SET score = DEFAULT;
```